# Error attempting to write history

Tags: r

Before a project is open, R rapidly throws this error:

[image]

Surprisingly, I do not find anything related to this error with google. Even if, apparently, it does not cause problems to the working session, I am interested in its effects, to avoid possible future inconveniences.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United   Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.4
```

Here an example of the subsequent working directory, even if this behaviour occurs for any project I open. It does not occurs when opening an isolated script.

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/MaurizioLocale/OneDrive/Data_Science/10_Capstone_project/CP_Natural_Language"
```

Comment: can you also show what you get when you type `getwd()` at the console? it might be RStudio trying to save history in a folder which you do not have write accesss.

Comment: I edited the question with the details you requested, hope it helps.

Comment: in RStudio menu bar, you can go to Tools -> Global Options and set your `Default working directory`  to a folder where you have write access. or you can uncheck the `Always save history (even when not saving .RData)`...hope that helps

Comment: It does. Now lets see what happens, thank you very much!